# Can one extend the domain of the square root $\sqrt{\cdot}$ to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: functions, common-root

Is it even allowed to do that? I know that it is defined to only return the positive solutions and is a function as such, but can one extend the domain with it still being called a function?

Comment: Which root function are you talking about? The zeroth root, the first root, the second root, the third root, fractional and negative roots - all have different issues and considerations. You need to clarify your question to get a good answer.

Comment: Fixed, I'm on mobile sry for formatting

Comment: A function does not have to be surjective (onto) to be a function. Consider the constant function, for example (this can be surjective, but there are obvious cases where it isn't, and limited cases where it is).

Comment: I know that, sorry, long time since I posted here, I hope it's clear now what I mean.

Comment: The crux here is that the square root of a negative number is not a real number, so this can't be a function. You can go $\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+\text { or } {\mathbb R}$ because the square root of a non-negative real number can be defined to be a non-negative real number.

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted to know, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a function from $[0,\infty) = \mathbb R^+$ to $\mathbb R$ (although not onto).

You can not extend a domain to where it is undefined.  But you can restrict it to where it is defined.

$\sqrt{}: \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+ \subset \mathbb R$ is a function.

Another way to put this is to note that part of the declaration of a function is a precise declaration of what the domain is.  So $\sqrt{}$ *is* a function upon the correct domain.  But the correct domain is *NOT* $\mathbb R$.

The declaration of the domain is often neglected, overlooked and misunderstood.  But it is a *essential* part of defining a function.  In fact, maybe the most important part.

Comment: So when creating a function I need to know where it is not defined/possible to define it and exclude those sets from my domain

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is considered will all real numbers as its domain, how do you define $f(-1)$?

Normally we do that by saying $f(-1) = i \in \mathbb{C}$ but you are asking about $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, I don't think there is a way to do that.